# Vmware tcServer for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, spring

From within `Eclipse Java EE - Juno`, *"new server wizard*" there is no `Vmware tcServer` option even after installing `Spring STS plugin` and `Vmware tcServe`r extension. Unlike with my Eclipse Indigo/Helios where there is a tcServer option.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a fresh eclipse juno install on apple mac os PPC 10.5.8. Installed VMware feature as described here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/STS/deploying-CF-Eclipse.html though no cloud foundry server appears as an option.